# Variable has been used before it has been assigned a value

Tags: vb.net

I can't find the answer to my specific problem anywhere so I figured I'd open a new question.

I have a program that converts text between ASCII and Binary. It does this by finding the input in the first array, getting the index of that input and looking at that index number in the second one, then writes what it found to another variable.

Here is the code:

```
Function ConvertBinaryToASCII(ByVal input As String) As String
    Dim ASCIIList() As String = {" ", "!", "a", "A", "b", "B", "c", "C", "d", "D", "e", "E", "f", "F", "g", "G", "h", "H", "i", "I", "j", "J", "k", "K", "l", "L", "m", "M", "n", "N", "o", "O", "p", "P", "q", "Q", "r", "R", "s", "S", "t", "T", "u", "U", "v", "V", "w", "W", "x", "X", "y", "Y", "z", "Z"}
    Dim BinaryList() As String = {"00100000", "00100001", "01100001", "01000001", "01100010", "01000010", "01100011", "01000011", "01100100", "01000100", "01100101", "01000101", "01100110", "01000110", "01100111", "01000111", "01101000", "01001000", "01101001", "01001001", "01101010", "01001010", "01101011", "01001011", "01101100", "01001100", "01101101", "01001101", "01101110", "01001110", "01101111", "01001111", "01110000", "01010000", "01110001", "01010001", "01110010", "01010010", "01110011", "01010011", "01110100", "01010100", "01110101", "01010101", "01110110", "01010110", "01110111", "01010111", "01111000", "01011000", "01111001", "01011001", "01111010", "01011010"}
    Dim BinarySubstrings = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length \ 8).[Select](Function(i) input.Substring(i * 8, 8)).ToArray()
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim result() As String
    Dim binaryMatch As Integer

    For Each e As String In BinarySubstrings
        binaryMatch = Array.IndexOf(BinaryList, e)
        result(counter) = ASCIIList(CInt(binaryMatch))
        counter += 1
    Next

    Return String.Join("", result)
End Function
```

The function works as intended except the problem is that no matter how I try to call or initialize `result` it always gives me some sort of error and I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: `Dim result() As String` is missing the size of the array. Maybe a `List(Of String)` would be better.

Comment: If I manually specify a length, it still gives an error, if I try to initialize it as `List(Of String)` it still gives an error, the error is always different but there's always an error.

Comment: the problem is does not mention the size of the array or initialize it, so it is better to change the result array declaration as `Dim result(55) As String` since the array having only 54 members and one additional ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a **List(Of String)** is better because you don't need to know the size of the array.
Of course you need to initialize the List(Of String) before usage.

```
Function ConvertBinaryToASCII(ByVal input As String) As String
    Dim ASCIIList() As String = .....
    Dim BinaryList() As String = ......
    Dim BinarySubstrings = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length \ 8).[Select](Function(i) input.Substring(i * 8, 8)).ToArray()
    Dim result = new List(Of String)()
    Dim binaryMatch As Integer

    For Each e As String In BinarySubstrings
        binaryMatch = Array.IndexOf(BinaryList, e)
        result.Add(ASCIIList(CInt(binaryMatch)))
    Next

    Return String.Join("", result.ToArray())
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You've declared an array, `result`, but the variable hasn't been assigned an instance of an array, so it's null. You can't add objects to a null array. Perhaps you meant this:

```
Dim result(BinarySubstrings.Length) As String
```

If you aren't sure about the size of result, consider using a `List(Of String)` as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

There's an easier way to do it:

```
Function BinaryStringToAscii(s As String) As String
    If s.Length Mod 8 <> 0 Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("String length is not a multiple of 8.")
    End If

    Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder

    For i = 0 To s.Length - 1 Step 8
        Dim bin = s.Substring(i, 8)
        sb.Append(Chr(Convert.ToInt32(bin, 2)))
    Next

    Return sb.ToString()

End Function
```

It uses a StringBuilder as in the end you need a string, and there is no need to use an array or list. The Convert.ToInt32 function has a useful overload where you can specify the base (2, 8, 10 or 16) to convert a string from.

And the converse:

```
Function AsciiToBinaryString(s As String) As String
    Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder
    For Each c In s
        sb.Append(Convert.ToString(Asc(c), 2).PadLeft(8, "0"c))
    Next

    Return sb.ToString()

End Function
```

Comment: +1 probably faster too, though you'd have to have a long string for it to matter enough

Comment: @Plutonix Oh, you had to go and mention the speed, didn't you? :) In my testing (.NET 4.5, release build), it's faster by a factor of about 16 for small strings (~100 ASCII characters) down to a factor of about 5 (~1,000,000 ASCII chars). And it uses less memory.

Comment: I'll try it out when i get home. If you want to check out the code and see if you can make any other optimizations, the SF project is [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/datatypecalculator/).